# Circle and circle collision (with physics), but when lots of circles pile up things go wrong

Tags: physics, python, pygame

I'm trying to make an as realistic as possible ball physics simulator. Currently, I worked out all the collisions between balls, and it works really well when there are few balls. But once you create around and over 400-500 balls, things start to get weird: The balls at the bottom get squished around, overlapping with one another. And once you add even more balls, things get even crazier, the balls start to almost teleport around at the bottom.

Since the balls are overlapping, I tried to push out the balls further when they collide, which caused even crazier shaking and teleporting.

I genuinely don't know what else I can do since the formula for collision seems to be correct.

Some screenshots:
With 100 balls:
[image: Balls piling up normally without glitching]
With over 600 balls:
[image: Balls teleporting and overlapping at the bottom]

Does anyone know what is happening and what is causing this? How can the code be improved to prevent it?

(For ease of testing, use scroll wheel to create lots of balls in quick succession)

Here is the code, it isn't too long:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import *
from math import *

WIDTH = 1200
HEIGHT = 800
FPS = 144
VEC = pygame.math.Vector2

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption("Bouncy balls with physics")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gravity = 3200
colors = range(50, 255, 10)
sizes = (15, 25)

absvec = lambda v: VEC(abs(v.x), abs(v.y))
inttup = lambda tup: tuple((int(tup[0]), int(tup[1])))

class Ball:
    instances = []
    regions = {}

    def __init__(self, pos):
        __class__.instances.append(self)
        self.pos = VEC(pos)
        self.region = inttup(self.pos // (sizes[1] * 2) + VEC(1, 1))
        if self.region in __class__.regions:
            __class__.regions[self.region].append(self)
        else:
            __class__.regions[self.region] = [self]
        self.vel = VEC(0, 0)
        self.radius = randint(*sizes)
        self.mass = self.radius ** 2 * pi
        self.color = (choice(colors), choice(colors), choice(colors))
        self.moving = True

    def update_position(self):
        self.vel.y += gravity * dt
        self.vel -= self.vel.normalize() * 160 * dt
        if -6 < self.vel.x < 6:
            self.vel.x = 0
        if -6 < self.vel.y < 6:
            self.vel.y = 0
        self.pos += self.vel * dt

        new_region = inttup(self.pos // (sizes[1] * 2) + VEC(1, 1))
        if self.region != new_region:
            if new_region in __class__.regions:
                __class__.regions[new_region].append(self)
            else:
                __class__.regions[new_region] = [self]
            __class__.regions[self.region].remove(self)
            self.region = new_region

    def update_pushout(self):
        self.collisions = []
        for x in range(self.region[0] - 1, self.region[0] + 2):
            for y in range(self.region[1] - 1, self.region[1] + 2):
                if (x, y) in __class__.regions:
                    for ball in __class__.regions[(x, y)]:
                        dist = self.pos.distance_to(ball.pos)
                        if dist < self.radius + ball.radius and ball != self:
                            self.collisions.append(ball)
                            overlap = -(dist - self.radius - ball.radius) * 0.5
                            self.pos += overlap * (self.pos - ball.pos).normalize()
                            ball.pos -= overlap * (self.pos - ball.pos).normalize()
    
    def update_collision(self):
        for ball in self.collisions:
            self.vel *= 0.85
            n = (ball.pos - self.pos).normalize()
            k = self.vel - ball.vel
            p = 2 * (n * k) / (self.mass + ball.mass)
            self.vel -= p * ball.mass * n
            ball.vel += p * self.mass * n

        if self.pos.x < self.radius:
            self.vel.x *= -0.8
            self.pos.x = self.radius
        elif self.pos.x > WIDTH - self.radius:
            self.vel.x *= -0.8
            self.pos.x = WIDTH - self.radius
        if self.pos.y < self.radius:
            self.vel.y *= -0.8
            self.pos.y = self.radius
        elif self.pos.y > HEIGHT - self.radius:
            if self.vel.y <= gravity * dt:
                self.vel.y = 0
            else:
                self.vel.y *= -0.8
            self.pos.y = HEIGHT - self.radius

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.pos, self.radius)

    def kill(self):
        __class__.instances.remove(self)
        __class__.regions[self.region].remove(self)
        del self

running = True
while running:
    dt = clock.tick_busy_loop(FPS) / 1000
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Bouncy balls with physics | FPS: {str(int(clock.get_fps()))} | Ball count: {len(Ball.instances)}")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mpos = VEC(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            if sum([len(balls) for balls in Ball.regions.values()]) <= 1000:
                Ball(mpos)
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_c:
                for ball in Ball.instances.copy():
                    ball.kill()

    for ball in Ball.instances:
        ball.update_position()
        ball.update_pushout()
        ball.update_collision()
        ball.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

This is the code I used that gets performed when two balls collide:

```
self.vel *= 0.85
n = (ball.pos - self.pos).normalize()
k = self.vel - ball.vel
p = 2 * (n * k) / (self.mass + ball.mass)
self.vel -= p * ball.mass * n
ball.vel += p * self.mass * n
```

gotten from this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609571/circle-and-circle-collision-with-physics-but-when-lots-of-circles-pile-up-thi). Cross-posting is not allowed on stack-exchange sites. If you decide to delete the other, then flag this question for a moderator and we'll be able to reopen it.

Comment: FWIW, I think code like this `ball.pos -= overlap * (self.pos - ball.pos).normalize()` will modify the balls position _after_ their own constraint have been tackled; this can result in that the balls that are handled _first_ will be much more pushed and displaced in a weird way than those pushed after. That's the kind of issue you can't solve in a single pass, you need multiple iterations per frame to resolve the constraints.

Comment: A way you could do this is do a pass for each ball, check all the collisions and store the constraints on that ball, then do another pass to resolve the constraints, then repeat until there is no (or an acceptable) overlapping. That's for _one_ physics frame.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe a way to patch this would be to change the way you iterate over your balls; instead of iterating over always in the same order, like this `for ball in Ball.instances:` randomly _shuffle_ the balls in the list before iterating over it. The idea is that it will not always be the same balls that'll accumulate the same errors. (And that's just a guess.)